# Анкетные конструкции. Каким членом предложения является слово после двоеточия?

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения, двоеточие

В анкетах и формах ввода данных часто встречаются следующие конструкции:

> Фамилия: Говоров.
>
> Пол: мужской.
>
> Образование: высшее.
>
> Телефон: 89151234567.
>
> Адрес: г. Москва, ул. Ленина, д. 1.

Каким членом предложения является слово после двоеточия?

Answer (score 1):

В анкетах после двоеточия стоит сказуемое. Назван предмет и его признак, в этом случае предмет - это подлежащее, а признак - сказуемое. Такое определение есть у Розенталя: Сказуемое - главный член двусоставного предложения, выражающий признак предмета, названного подлежащим. Всё вроде сходится.

Цель урока: научиться решать задачи. Здесь то же самое: цель - подлежащее, научиться - сказуемое.

Если поставить тире, то получится обычное предложение, оформленное по правилам пунктуации.

Если поставить двоеточие, то получится пояснительный вариант этого же предложения с тем же значением, потому что двоеточие предупреждает о  последующем пояснении.

Зачем говорить об определениях или еще как-то усложнять тему. Мы в любой момент можем остановиться и эту паузу обозначить двоеточием. Можно вспомнить пример с пропущенным обобщающим словом (на заседании присутствовали:).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В  [книге Добромыслова, Розенталя (внизу страницы)](http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/znaki-prepinaniya-pri-pryamoy-137342.html) эти два случая рассматриваются как различные (назывное и двусоставное предложения).

Comment: Да Вы посмотрите, что это за книга, она дореформенная еще. https://dic.academic.ru/book.nsf/61041702/Трудные+вопросы+грамматики+и+правописания.  Тогда другое понимание языка было. Это предложение не может быть назывным (номинативным). Оно не называет предмет, а связывает предмет и признак, оно двусоставное Назывное предложение - это существительное или сочетание на его основе в И.п. Зима. Вот озеро. Картины на стене. И т.д.

Comment: Хочу вас заверить, что с того времени в синтаксисе никаких реформ не было. Поэтому называть книгу дореформенной неправильно.

Comment: Ну формально неправильно (это гротескное выражение), а по сути верно. Ей же сто лет почти,  за это время понимание грамматики во многом изменилось, по крайней мере для номинативных  предложений уж точно.  Назывные предложения называют предмет как существующий в реальном времени времени, это их основная функция. А в заданной теме предмет соотносится с признаком.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, это вообще не есть полноценные предложения, потому и говорить о членах смысла нет. Интересно, в связи с чем такой вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос возник из-за использования двоеточия. Хочется понять, как согласовать такую постановку знаков препинания с существующими правилами пунктуации. Как интерпретировать подобные конструкции синтаксически?

Comment: Для таких конструкций существующие правила пунктуации не работают. Самый естественный знак здесь двоеточие – его чаще всего и ставят. Можно и тире.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Скажите, пожалуйста, как тогда объяснить постановку двоеточия в следующем случае: «В случае возникновения вопросов звонить по телефону: 89151234567.»? Здесь ведь «полноценное» предложение. Каким членом предложения является номер в таком случае?

Comment: А здесь и не нужно двоеточия. Ну, видимо, определение. По телефону (какому?) такому-то. И все равно непонятно, зачем вам нужен этот член предложения.

Comment: @serggovroff, смысл двоеточия в приведенном вами примере заключается в пояснении, разъяснении. Т. е двоеточие предупреждает, что дальше последует пояснение того, о чем говорится в первой части.

Comment: Спасибо.
Просто мне показался интересным следующий случай из книги Розенталя. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, [эту ссылку (внизу страницы).](http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/znaki-prepinaniya-pri-pryamoy-137342.html)
Рассмотрим предложение: «Цель урока: научиться решать задачи».  Здесь инфинитив поясняет цель и является определением (какая?). В случае тире это двусоставное предложение («Цель урока – научиться решать задачи.»). Вы согласны с такими выводами? Здесь конструкция является «полноценным» предложением?

Comment: serggovoroff, все верно. Инфинитив из примера Розенталя выступает в роли определения.А тире указывает на пропуск члена предложения.

Comment: @Серж Тогда в случае анкет и форм ввода данных нельзя вести речь о членах предложения, т. к. это не предложение. Когда все-таки подобная конструкция является предложением, то часть после двоеточия, поясняющая смысл первой части, является определением. Вы согласны?

Comment: @Серж Ответьте, пожалуйста. Требуется Ваше мнение.

Comment: @ serggovoroff, простите За задержку.  Действительно, говорить о синтаксическом разборе анкетных "конструкций" нет смысла.

Comment: Если же отвечать на вопрос: "Каким членом предложения является слово после двоеточия?", то надо заметить, все зависит от контекста. Например: Пол: мужской. Здесь "мужской" определение.

Comment: @Серж Спасибо большое за ответ. Я согласен с Вашей точкой зрения. Последний вопрос: как понимать случаи, когда после двоеточия стоит существительное? Здесь тоже многое зависит от контекста. Например, "Гарантия: 2 года", "Производитель: ООО "Звезда". "2 года", "ООО "Звезда" – это определения? Или же такие примеры следует понимать как 2 назывных предложения?

Comment: @Серж Ответьте, пожалуйста

Comment: @serggovoroff, я обязательно отвечу - вечером.

Comment: @serggovorof, все же такие конструкции трудно отнести к предложениям. т. к. в отличии от предложения, они не обладают коммуникативной функцией, у них нет модальности. Такие конструкции можно отнести к Именительному темы. Именительный темы выступает в функции названий научных трудов, произведений художественной литературы, названий глав, подразделов; в функции пунктов плана к тексту и т. д.

Comment: @Серж Спасибо за ответ. Это касается всех подобных конструкций? "Пол: мужской", "Цель: научиться..." – тоже именительные темы? Если нет, то тогда часть аналогичных конструкций мы признаем предложением, часть – нет.

Comment: @Серж Спасибо за терпение. Прочтите, пожалуйста, следующие мысли и выскажите свое мнение по этому поводу.
Случаи с тире и двоеточием отличаются интонационно: «Производитель – ООО Звезда», «Производитель: ООО Звезда». В случае двоеточия мы «дробим» предложение на две части. Вторая часть поясняет первую (тема и раскрытие этой темы). При двоеточии вторую часть нельзя рассматривать как именную часть составного именного сказуемого (как в случае тире).

Comment: Встает вопрос: как понимать такую пояснительную связь?
Именительный темы, по моему мнению, все-таки немного другая конструкция, которая имеет больше интонационную роль.

Comment: Можно ли считать вторую часть пояснительным членом предложения? Пояснительный член предложения – это «особый» член предложения? Или же пояснительным членом может быть определение, дополнение и другие члены? Может ли пояснительным членом быть подлежащее и сказуемое? Например, рассмотрим случай «Производитель: ООО Звезда». «ООО Звезда» – это пояснительный член предложения, являющийся тем же членом предложения, что и поясняемый член, т. е. «ООО Звезда» тоже является подлежащим. @Серж Согласны ли вы с этим?

Comment: @serggovorof, если это анкетные конструкции, то, наверное, и их можно признать именительный темы. Однако говорить, что все подобные конструкции, можно отнести к  ИТ - неправильно. Возможно, при другом контексте, не анкетных конструкциях) их можно рассматривать как предложение.

Comment: При двоеточии, действительность, нельзя рассматривать вторую часть как именную часть составного именного сказуемого .

Comment: Пояснительный член предложение немного другое понятие. Пояснение — это обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами. Ср.:еред пояснительным членом предложения обычно стоят слова именно, а именно, то есть (при их отсутствии в предложении эти слова могут быть вставлены): Она была воспитана no-старинному,  то есть окружена мамушками, нянюшками, подружками и сенными девушками (П.)

Comment: Все, выхожу. Пишете, если что непонятно - отвечу.

Comment: @Серж Спасибо! Я соглашусь с Вами насчет именительного темы. Но возник другой вопрос. Есть ли различия между двумя случаями: «Виды общественного транспорта: автобус, трамвай, метро.» и «Предпочитаемый вид транспорта: автомобиль.»? В первом случае имеем обобщающее слово с однородными членами, однородные члены являются теми же членами предложения, что и обобщающее слово, т. е. подлежащими. И вся конструкция – это одно назывное (номинативное?) предложение. Или же первый случай – это тоже именительный темы?

Comment: Во втором случае «Предпочитаемый вид транспорта» – это именительный темы. А что такое «автомобиль» в данном случае? Как охарактеризовать вторую часть? Как назывное предложение?

Comment: @Серж «Виды общественного транспорта: автобус, трамвай, метро.» – это обобщающее слово с однородными членами или именительный темы? Независимо от того, анкетные конструкции или нет. Простите, пожалуйста, за беспокойство

Comment: @serggovoroff, порой бывает трудно различить ИТ от схожих по структуре предложений.  Возвращаясь к вашему вопроса, можно сказать, что это может быть обобщающее слово с однородными членами, может быть и ИТ. Все зависит от контекста. Напр., если заголовок статьи, то лучше кфалифицировать это, как ИТ.

Comment: Что касается конструкции «Предпочитаемый вид транспорта: автомобиль». Такие конструкции лучше рассматривать, как единую синтаксическую конструкцию.

Comment: Если еще остались вопросы, задавайте, как отдельный вопрос,по "кнопке" " Задать вопрос". Развернутые обсуждения здесь запрещаются.

Comment: @Серж Спасибо! "единая синтаксическая конструкция" – подразумевается ИТ? Вся конструкция «Предпочитаемый вид транспорта: автомобиль» – ИТ? Или это конструкция, которая включает в себя ИТ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81511/discussion-between-serggovoroff-and-).